# How much nonlinearity could z3 handle in practice?

Tags: z3, z3py

My apologies if this question is ill-phrased but I'm trying to use z3 (in python with the language binding) to solve some nonlinear equations, but unfortunately neither the qfnra-nlsat nor the general solver could solve the following system unless a, b and c are all given:

```
    y == 0.001 * (a ** 2.07) * (b ** 0.9) * (c ** 0.7) + 0.002 
    y > 0.0
```

I tried with the following tactic:

```
    t = z3.Then('simplify', 'qfnra-nlsat')
```

and I also tried substituting the nonlinear parts with some intermediate names and add the exponential parts back in later with incremental solver using `push()`. But z3 basically gets stuck (longer than 1 hour as far as I tried) in both cases.

I'm a newbie to CSP and the theoretical background involved, sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm wondering if such nonlinearity is beyond (empirically) solvable by z3 or I'm not using it correctly? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's the python code that fails on my machine:

```
    import z3
    a = z3.Real('a')
    b = z3.Real('b')
    c = z3.Real('c') 
    y = z3.Real('y')

    eq = [ 
        y == 0.001 * (a ** 2.07) * (b ** 0.9) * (c ** 0.7) + 0.002,
        y >= 0.0 
    ]

    t = z3.Then('simplify', 'qfnra-nlsat')
    s = t.solver()
    s.add(eq)
    r = s.check()
    print r
    m = s.model()
    print m
```

Here's the output:

```
    unknown
    [y = 1/500 ]
```

**Edit:**

It seems that the latest code from z3 git repo is kinda broken. I tried with 4.4.1 release and it all worked out.

A follow up question though, if I just add one more constraint below:

```
    a == 16.0
```

And z3 gets stuck, which I could not understand...It seems that the additional constraint above is pretty trivial, an initial guess of b and c being both 1s should solve the system, but I guess that's not how z3 works? Any idea on how to solve the system with this new constraint?

Comment: Forgot to mention, z3 gets stuck when a, b and c are all given. If I leave out any of the rhs vars or assign value to y, z3 would just give up and return unknown immediately.

Comment: Also, I declared all the varibles as type Real.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming I didn't make some translation mistake, I tried this out in the pure SMT-LIB interface and it seems to work fine.

If you still have some problems after looking at this, please encode your entire example that is failing, as maybe you have some constraints that you didn't include that is causing it to fail. Or, possibly the overloaded Python operators (e.g., `**`) are not being interpreted properly (although that does seem to be the right usage for power), so you may want to use the Z3 Python API's functions for various expressions.

I included this `x` variable that's extra just to double check I was using `^` correctly as power, and it seems right (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/plLQJ ):

```
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const a Real)
(declare-const b Real)
(declare-const c Real)

; y == 0.001 * (a ** 2.07) * (b ** 0.9) * (c ** 0.7) + 0.002
(assert (= y (+ (* 0.001 (^ a 2.07) (^ b 0.9) (^ c 0.7)) 0.002)))
(assert (> y 0.0))

(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-model)

(assert (> x 1.0))
(assert (= x (^ 5.0 2.5))) ; check ^ means pow
(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-model)
```

This yields:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun a () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun b () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun c () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun y () Real
    (+ (/ 1.0 500.0)
   (* (- (/ 69617318994479297159441705182250977318952641791835914067365099344218850343780027694073822279020999411953209540560859156221731465694293028234177768119402105034869871366755227547291324996387.0
            4000.0))
      (^ (/ 1.0 8.0) 207.0))))
)
sat
(model 
  (define-fun a () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun b () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun c () Real
    (- 1.0))
  (define-fun x () Real
    (root-obj (+ (^ x 2) (- 3125)) 2))
  (define-fun y () Real
    (+ (/ 1.0 500.0)
   (* (- (/ 69617318994479297159441705182250977318952641791835914067365099344218850343780027694073822279020999411953209540560859156221731465694293028234177768119402105034869871366755227547291324996387.0
            4000.0))
      (^ (/ 1.0 8.0) 207.0))))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping but weird as it sounds, the exact same equations fail on my local machine. I don't have any other constraints in the system and I'm pretty sure in the z3 python API it says `Like Python, ** is the power operator`, so I guess it's not because of the power operators? Any suggestions where I should look into next?

Comment: I translated your SMT-LIB code back into python and run it with both the general solver and `qfnra-nlsat`, it reported `unknown` in both cases and failed to find the models. I'm thinking I might be doing something stupid here but I really can't see what I did wrong...

Comment: @weil0ng You could try dumping the model to SMT format from within the Python interface and see if it produces the same set of assertions that Taylor wrote.  I don't know the Python API well, but the C++ API has a toSmt() method in the Solver class.